# IBM Infosphere Data Architect: How to debug SQL query execution

Tags: sql, db2

I am writing/running fairly complex SQL queries in Infosphere Data Architect for IBM DB2 9.7. Is it possible to somehow debug the execution? Printing out debug information line-by-line is sufficient, or then use of break points.

I am having problems in finding this...

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409melnyk/ you should look at that article